# Pandas Incremental Group Counter

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am having a hard time pulling this off. But would I'm trying to do in Pandas is count incrementally the number of child rows, grouped by Child and Master and sorted by Date desc.

There may be duplicates so I want to keep the count over the duplicate rows, as demonstrated in this table with the "Counter" column being the ideal addition to the dataframe.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

I tried the following but it continues to count up over the duplicate rows:

df['Counter'] = df.groupby(['Master', 'Child']).cumcount() + 1

Comment: Please don't add your input as an image

Comment: use from ngroup() method

Comment: Could you `drop_duplicates` first?

Comment: @TaxpayersMoney this is ultimately the direction I went. First Drop Duplicates, then cumcount(), then Left Merge worked out great.